# Do I need to free private interface fields in .NET?

Tags: .net, memory-management, interface, memory-leaks

From my understanding an interfaced resource is freed once the reference count on the interface gets to 0.

Consider the following private field:

```
private IMyInterface _field = new DisposableObject()
```

Would I need to still explicitly free this field up in the class e.g. make the class implemented `IDisposable` and free it up on `Dispose`? Or would it be freed up automatically because I am using an interface?

I had a similar situation in Delphi and it was causing a memory leak which confused me a little as I always thought interfaced objects did not need to be freed (as they are reference counted). To fix the memory leak, I had to  store the concrete type and free it up on destroy.

I guess what I am really getting at is *why* do I need to free it up if I am using an interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET does not use reference counting to determine when resources are garbage collected. Objects will be collected when there are no live references to an object anywhere in the program. This is done by an object-graph traversal rather than reference counting, so that circular references do not leak resources.

If a class with unmanaged resources is coded correctly, then the call to `Dispose` will be optional. The resources will be cleaned up in the finalizer when the garbage collection occurs regardless.

`Dispose` does not affect the lifetime of an object. It will be garbage collected at some time after there are no live references to the object remaining.

The lifetime of an object is also not affected by whether the variable that references it is of an interface or object type. Setting the variable to null will remove the live reference and—if there are no other references to the object—allow the object to be collected.

Comment: +1 - This is pretty much the explanation I was looking for. In Delphi if I use an interface to reference a resource under normal circumstances I wouldn't need to explicitly free it up.

Answer (score 3):

> I guess what I am really getting at is why do I need to free it up if I am using an interface?

An interface only tells you *how* to correctly dispose the resource, not *when* to do it. You have to decide that yourself.

A good rule of thumb is that whoever originally requested the resource is also responsible for disposing it. If your object owns the resource then it should dispose the resource when it is itself disposed (or earlier, if it is no longer needs the resource). If it doesn't own the resource but is just using it, then it usually shouldn't dispose it.

Answer (score 1):

When your class contains disposable fields, that are managed by your class - I mean, they're isntantiated inside your class- , then your class should implement the `IDisposable` interface as well.

If you do not dispose Disposable objects as soon as you do not need them anymore, you're not sure *when* the objects will be disposed.

Answer (score 0):

Using interfaces does not mean that you don't need to apply proper disposing techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should implement IDisposable (how to do that depends on your class. Look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/idisposable.aspx) for some good advice).

Interface or not, you created the object, so you are (in general) responsible for cleaning it up. Since its disposable, that's the way to go.

Memory leaks in the classic sense are almost impossible due to the garbage collection, but disposable objects usually deal with other resources (like files, database connections, COM-objects or whatever), so resource leaks are still possible.